# Why does TinyMVC is not loading the controllers?

Tags: php

I have a problem with TinyMVC. I'm really new with this "MVC framework".

I download the last version of TinyMVC here: http://www.tinymvc.com/download/

I just followed the guide and I have arrived on the controller documentation: http://www.tinymvc.com/documentation/index.php/Documentation:Controllers

I followed the instruction and I have created a hello.php file inside **myapp/controllers/hello.php**

This is the code of hello.php

```
class Hello_Controller extends TinyMVC_Controller
{
  function index()
  {
    echo "Hello World.";
  }
  function time()
  {
    echo "The time is now.";
  }
}
```

I also have put this **.htaccess** inside htdocs (where index.php is)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now the problem is that seems tinyMVC is not loading the controllers correctly.

I just tried:

```
http://localhost/myproject/www (AND I SEE THE DEFAULT CONTROLLER correctly)

http://localhost/myproject/www/hello (I STILL SEE THE DEFAULT CONTROLLER)

http://localhost/myproject/www/hello/time (I get the follow error)

Error: 0
Message: Unknown controller method 'time'
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\tinymvc\sysfiles\plugins\tinymvc_controller.php
Line: 58
```

I do not thing it was wrong, but my controllers are not loaded correctly.

Comment: Try the SVN version, it has more fixes http://stackoverflow.com/a/12170022/685107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with line 188 in TinyMVC.php.

Change file_exists to stream_resolve_include_path (File located at tinymvc/sysfiles/