# TinyMVC always shows 'default' controller

Tags: php, frameworks

I was following documentaion till the end, tested one html template with smarty and then cut it. Then I found out that controllers do not work as expected – whatever name I create in `myapp/conrollers`, `'hello.php'` for example, that contains class described in docs, i. e.

```
class Hello_Controller extends TinyMVC_Controller
{
  function index()
  {
    echo "Hello World.";
  }
  function time()
  {
    echo "The time is now.";
  }
}
```

I can’t show it. So the name of the file is a prefix for the controller class name, all seems to be ok here, but going to /index.php/hello returns what is in `'default.php'`. I’ve even tried to change default controller to 'hello' in myapp/configs/application.php by setting `$config['default_controller']`, but the framework behaves like if it’s always work with the 'default.php'. There is no errors on screen or in logs (I checked twice every option in configs of my web server and interpreter), I totally don’t know what to do with that goddamn piece of crap, I can’t even write on its forum because waiting for ‘administration approval’ for several days.

Comment: Why, if you think of this framework as "that goddamn piece of crap", don't you go searching for another framework that is a little more mainstream, like codeigniter, cake or zend? They have all great support and a lot of programmers use them.

Comment: Cause I need something _that_ small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig inside of the framework to find an answer. And it is when it checks for a controller file it uses file_exists() which do not respect include path. Googling ‘TinyMVC+file_exists’ gave me link to [that topic](http://www.tinymvc.com/f/index.php?topic=382.0), where is written that they had fixed it in SVN version.